# Does $\mathbb R P^n$ retract to $\mathbb R P^k$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I was trying to prove that no such retraction exists. For $k$ odd this follows directly from the (co-)homology groups of these spaces.

However, for $k$ even I have no idea how to proceed and if it is even true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true as long as $0<k<n$ (it is trivially false for $k=0$ and $k=n$), and follows immediately from the ring structure of the mod 2 cohomology.  We have $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^{n+1})$ with $|x|=1$.  If $n>k$, then there is no injective homomorphism of graded rings $\mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^{k+1})\to \mathbb{Z}/2[x]/(x^{n+1})$ (since $x$ must map to an element $y$ such that $y^{k+1}=0$, and the only such element in degree $1$ is $y=0$).

(I assume you are interested only in the case $k\leq n$, where $\mathbb{R}P^k$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ in the canonical way.  If $k>n$, then $\mathbb{R}P^k$ does not even embed in $\mathbb{R}P^n$.)

Comment: Thx. This looks convincing. Just to make sure, that I got it right:  
If $r^*$ is injective, then $r^*(x)=y$ and thus $0=r^*(0)=r^*(x^{k+1})=(r^*(x))^{k+1}=y^{k+1}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: If by $y$ you mean the nonzero element in $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^n)$, then yes, that is one way of saying it.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $0<k<n$, $\pi_i(\mathbb{R}P^n)=1$ if $1<i<n$ and $\pi_n(\mathbb{R}P^n)=\mathbb{Z}$. A retract $r:\mathbb{R}P^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^k$ with $i:\mathbb{R}P^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}P^n$ implies that $(r\circ i)_k=id:\pi_k(\mathbb{R}P^k)\rightarrow \pi_k(\mathbb{R}P^k)$ is trivial. 
Contradiction.

Suppose that $k>n$, since $H^{k}(\mathbb{R}P^k,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z/2})$ and 
$H^{k}(\mathbb{R}P^n,\mathbb{Z}/2)=0$, this implies that $(r\circ i)_k^*=id:H^{k}(\mathbb{R}P^k,\mathbb{Z}/2)\rightarrow H^{k}(\mathbb{R}P^k,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is trivial contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, but the result is not clear to me. How does this imply that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ cannot be a **retract** of $\mathbb{R}P^k$?

Comment: Because a retraction would implies the both spaces have the same cohomology.

Comment: No. That would be a **deformation** retraction.

Comment: A point is a retract of any non-empty space, but clearly not every space has the homology of a point.

Comment: Doesn't the argument for $k<n$ only imply that $i_{*}: 1= \pi_k(\mathbb R P^k) \to \pi_k(\mathbb R P^n)= \mathbb Z$ is injective, which is not a contradiction?

Comment: you have inversed the role of $1$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, it is basically that.

Comment: So your proof is wrong?

Comment: No it is not, I see basically a retraction between $RP^k$ and $RP^n$ implies that $(r\circ i)_k:\pi_k(RP^k)\rightarrow RP^k$ is the trivial morphism this is in contradiction with the fact that this morphism should be the identity morphism and $\pi_k(\mathbb{R}P^k)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If I understand you right, you say that $(r \circ i)_k$ factors through the trivial group and as $\pi_k (\mathbb R P^k)$ is not trivial,  $(r \circ i)_k$ cannot be the identity?

Comment: It is exactly that.